# Appropriate storage to store all keyboard and mouse events on my computer?

Tags: data

I'd like to build detail analytics of my computer usage to try and detect patterns and improvement opportunities. So I'm building a software to record every mouse click, keyboard event and window activation event with a timestamp.

This is potentially a huge amount of data streaming continuously to disk and I'm somewhat afraid that it'll shorten its lifespan. For now I'm sequentially appending them to an unencrypted file but I'd like to do better.

What is an appropriate database or datastore? And is there a lightweight way to protect/encrypt this data?

EDIT: about the number of daily events: I'm a software developer so I type and do "normal" stuff on the computer all day.

Comment: Is this for Windows? If yes, get a copy of Sysinternals Process Monitor (which is free), enable a filter for the events you are interested in, and let it run in the background for, lets says, half an hour. That should give you a quick estimate how much data you will have to expect. For other operating systems, there will probably be similar tools.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You overestimate the amount of data you'll collect, and underestimate the reliability of modern hard disks.

Use whatever database you're most familiar with. Once you recorded data for several months in a row, you'll have more concrete view of (1) how much space does it take, and (2) is the database optimal for that. Chances are, you'll just find that you need to add a few indexes here and there, and nothing more.

Comment: Just to slightly extend, if you practice clean coding, switching database (format or provider) is reasonably easy to do, which is why you don't need to fret over making the right choice from the get go. Deal with issues as they come, and use your preference until it proves incompatible with your requirements.

Comment: Local Sqlite FTW

Answer (score 1):

You mention storage and I first thought of a database. I would also mention that you should look at a few different options existing solutions for logging large amounts of data. Servers generally log to flatfiles for instance. Appending to a file is quick. Though you would have to parse it to make sense of it.

That being said, if you have a layer that abstracts the writing of the data you can just write different adapters if you need to modify it later on. I tend to start with the most straight-forward to implement and then see if I need to increase performance. As long as you have a simple common interface for writing the events, you should be in a good spot.